# Removing a file from a protected folder in Mojave

Tags: terminal, mojave, folders, iterm, soundflower

**Background**

I am trying to remove Sound Flower from my Mac. I found some relative files in 3 places. I removed 2 of them but the third one is in a folder that will not allow me to remove it.

**Example**

The file is in,

```
/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-1C2FCFF8-A394-409D-8DB3-E7885C0D5E81/QuarantineRoot/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions
```

The file name is,

```
Soundflower.kext
```

When I try to remove it like this,

```
rm -rf Soundflower.kext
```

I get this error!

```
rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources: Operation
not permitted rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature: Operation
not permitted rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents/MacOS/Soundflower:
Operation not permitted rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents/MacOS: Operation
not permitted rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents/Info.plist: Operation not
permitted rm: Soundflower.kext/Contents: Operation not permitted rm:
Soundflower.kext: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried, `sudo`, `sudo su` and adding the Terminal and iTerm to 
   *Full Disk Access*

settings in *Security & Privacy* in system settings. Once I added them I closed and restarted my terminals.

I still get the error.

**Question**

How do I remove this file from the path mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the file without disabling SIP by booting to Recovery and then deleting the file in the terminal. The system disk is actually mounted read/write in Mojave Recovery, so the trick is that you have to refer to the drive by starting at /Volumes/yourdrivenamehere.  So in this case the command to remove the file would be:

```
rm -rf /Volumes/yourdrivenamehere/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-1C2FCFF8-A394-409D-8DB3-E7885C0D5E81/QuarantineRoot/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to disable System Integrity Protection and **remove** /Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-1C2FCFF8-A394-409D-8DB3-E7885C0D5E81/QuarantineRoot/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext (and then re-enable System Integrity Protection).

To enable or disable System Integrity Protection, you must boot to Recovery OS and run the csrutil(1) command from the Terminal.

- Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the Command and R keys at startup.
- Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu.
- Enter the following command

  ```
  csrutil disable
  ```

  (or `crsutil enable`)